# got stuck in flutter splash screen : Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am stuck in flutter splash screen error which shown below:

```
    E/flutter ( 5472): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5472): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5472): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
E/flutter ( 5472): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 5472): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2185:40)
E/flutter ( 5472): #2      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1801:22)
E/flutter ( 5472): #3      _SplashState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:demo1/splash/splash.dart:19:25)
E/flutter ( 5472): #4      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:325:39)
E/flutter ( 5472): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 5472): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 5472): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 5472): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 5472): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 5472): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 5472): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter ( 5472): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter ( 5472): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter ( 5472): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter ( 5472): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Comment: please paste relevant code here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload some relevant code.
and i think you called setState before build.
Please add below condition before called setState

```
if(this.mounted) {
 setState((){});
}
```